# Determine whether a range of cells contains a substring of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to determine whether a range of cells contains a substring of another cell.
In this concrete example, for every cell in Column B individually, I want to find out whether any value of Column A is a substring of the cell.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42: | 123: Lorem ipsum | Yes |
| 123 | 42: dolor sit amet | Yes |
| 456 | test 123: At vero eos | Yes |
| 987 | Foo Bar | No |

I tried to look up existing solutions but could only find solutions to a similar problem: "Find out whether "42:" is a substring of any of Column B. I am not trying to find a substring in a set of strings. I want to search a set and find values that are substrings of a specific value

Comment: Would you only allow for trailing colon's? Or are you interested in any occurence of the substring despite following characters?

Comment: How do you get a yes for 123? it doesn't have the colon.

Comment: I am interested in any occurence of the substring despite following characters.

Comment: 123 is a substring of "test 123: At vero eos"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&SUBSTITUTE(A$1:A$4,":",)&" "," "&SUBSTITUTE(B1,":",)&" ")))>0
```

Or change `SUM()` with `SUMPRODUCT()` in older versions of Excel.

---

Note that the above would assume that the only other character allowed other than digits are colons. And they could be anywhere in the string e.g.: `1:2:3:::4:`. It's up to you to decide wheather or not that is too likely.